# redirecting url with parameters to same url without parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Using the file .htaccess, I am trying to redirect urls like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/a-page/?fp=123&sp=456&tp=789
```

to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/a-page/
```

so basically redirecting url not caring about params values to the same url without any param.

I have used RewriteCond/RewriteRule, Redirect and RedirectMatch but without any luck.

My latest try was:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
 RewriteRule ^a-page/$ http://www.mysite.com/a-page/? [L,R=301]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: [First thing you might want to get rid of](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) is `(.*)+`. Just make that `.+` if you want to require at least one character.

Comment: A path, for RewriteRule, in a directory context (.htaccess or <Directory>), never start with a slash.

Comment: yes thanks, although still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Are you sure url rewriting is enabled? (implies at least AllowOverride FileInfo + RewriteEngine on) Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess? PS: Redirect* cannot work, they won't handle the query string.

Comment: Your latest code should work "as is" so there is some other issue that is causing problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found a solution:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} . [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /a-page/
RewriteRule ^ a-page/? [L,R=301]
```