# htaccess redirect url with parameters to same url without parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

trying to redirect a url with ending parameter to same url without that parameter on the same domain

```
www.mydomain.com/efg/abc?id=303
to
www.mydomain.com/efg/abc
```

found [this answer on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788128/redirecting-url-with-parameters-to-same-url-without-parameters) and try to use it but it doesn't work for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /efg/abc
RewriteRule ^efg/abc? [L,R=302]
```

would appreciate any help.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=303$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^efg/abc/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,L,R=302]
```

`?` at the end of target URI will strip off any previous query string.

Comment: hi @anubhava, is this rule specific to www.mydomain.com/efg/abc?id=303  ?
i need it to be specific.  so that other url's ending with "id=" are not effected...

Answer (score 0):

You will basically want to drop the query string.  The last line you have with the abc? is not correct because it doesn't redirect anywhere.

Here is what should do the trick (this line alone and be sure that you have enabled modrewrite in .htaccess already):

```
RewriteRule ^efg/abc$ /efg/abc? [L,R=301]
```

I tested the above on a test domain of mine and it did the trick.